Error propagation: How to sum errors over 2D grid?
I have a dataset with worldwide mass change data and their uncertainty from glaciers. Both have dimensions 720,360,45 with the first two dimensions 'i,j' (lat,lon) coordinates and the third dimension 'k' the time (i.e. 45 years). Each pixel has an annual mass change value and associated uncertainty on that annual mass change (units: Gigatonnes).
I applied for each pixel the error propagation formula through the time dimension k:
total_err_pixel(i,j) = sqrt((err_year(i,j,k))^2 + 
   (err_year2(i,j,k+1))^2 + ... + 
   (err_year(i,j,k+45))^2)
total_err_pixel(i+1,j) = sqrt((err_year(i+1,j,k))^2 + 
   (err_year2(i+1,j,k+1))^2 + ... + 
   (err_year(i+1,j,k+45))^2)  

and so on ...

This results  in a 2D grid (720x360) with total error values propagated throughout these 45 years. Now my question is: to get a total uncertainty value on the worldwide glacier mass changes over 45 years, can I sum the errors over the entire grid or do I need to apply again the error propagation formula, but now in space (for each pixel i,j)?
total_error = sqrt((total_err_pixel(i,j))^2 + 
    (total_err_pixel(i+1,j))^2 + ... + 
    (total_err_pixel(i+720,j+360)^2)  


Welcome to CV.  Could you explain what these "error values" are and how they are measured?  My concern is whether they are independent measurement errors or do they incorporate components that might be (strongly) correlated over time, space, or both?  The distinction can lead to huge differences in the solution.

It is usual for longitude to have a range from $-180^\circ$ to $+180^\circ$ and latitude from $-90^\circ$ to $+90^\circ$.  If you are using $\frac12^\circ \times \frac12^\circ$ grid "squares" to get your $720\times360$, remember that the areas of those near the poles are much smaller than those near the equator.

Hi @whuber, thanks for the comment! The calculation of the error component is quite extensive. The gridpoint mass change uncertainty comes from the combination of 3 independent errors: The error relative to the specific regional mass balance (i.e. annual measurements of ice melt by glaciologists/satellites), the error relative to the gridpoint area (i.e. the total surface area of the grid), and the error relative to the glacier area change rate (i.e. how glaciers have shrunk over a year of time in that pixel). These 3 errors are combined by to the law of random error propagation. Units are Gt.

@whuber a full description is given in (e.g. page 34): https://datastore.copernicus-climate.eu/documents/derived-gridded-glacier-mass-change/C3S2_312a_Lot4.WP2-FDDP-GL-v1_202212_MC_ATBD-v4_i1.1.pdf

@Henry thanks for mentioning this! I have also thought about it. Glacier mass changes and their uncertainty are in units of Gt (Gigatonnes). It is a unit of mass from the loss of all glaciers in a certain pixel. I am not sure if it requires an area-weighted operation in that case.

I believe satellites do not actually measure ice melt: don't they estimate differences from one year to the next?  If so, the "law of random propagation," whatever it might be, would be invalid.  Indeed, in that (simplified) situation the total mass change would be estimated simply as the difference between the very last and very first observation, ignoring all intermediate values.  Regardless, any estimates of mass changes in consecutive years are likely to be strongly negatively correlated, causing that propagation formula to grossly overestimate the net error.

Concerning area weighting (which grows in importance towards both poles), see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127165 for a simple accurate procedure.
